# Electron: Call a function in a different javascript from index.js

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to call a function in `second_script.js` when the window is in focus, which is detected from my `main.js` (index.js) file. The `second_script.js` is used within a different HTML file as well.

**main.js**

```
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
    resizable: false,
    frame: true
  })

  win.on('focus', function () {
    call_that_function();
  });
```

**second_script.js**

This is located in `scripts/second_script.js` and used in a different HTML file.

```
function call_that_function() {
    //code
}
```

How do I bridge this gap such that the main.js will call that function whenever my window is in focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron is based on `node.js`.

Export that function in your `second_script.js` and then import/require it and call it inside your `main.js`.

Another way to communicate inside Electron is using the [ipcMain](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main):

```
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');
```

Spy on messages like below inside your `second_script.js`:

```
ipcMain.on('CHANNEL_NAME', (event, arg) => {
  console.log('message received', event, args);
  // call your func here
);
```

Send messages like below inside your `main.js`:

```
win.on('focus', function () {
  ipcRenderer.send('CHANNEL_NAME', 'ping');
});
```